# How to show the On-Screen-Keyboard in Windows 7/8 by clicking on a text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

Is there a way to trigger and show the On-Screen-Keyboard in Windows 7/8 when the user clicks onto a text-input (like a form in a normal html page)?
I think that the behaviour is similar of that of mobile-phones or tablets, but i would have a solution for computer desktop. 
So, the questions, in detail, are:
1 - It is possible to trigger the native Windows On-Screen-Keyboard, by clicking in an input text **or** by pressing a button in the web page? I think that i should use javascript/jquery, but i'm not sure...
2 - I found this plugin http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-screen-keyboard-plugin/ that seems nice, **but** 
      a - I did not understand exactly how to install it
     b - I also need the option of automatic scan keys of the on-screen-keyboard (in the Windows         native on-screen-keyboard this option is present)...is there a possibility to implement this         function in the plugin?

Thanks

Comment: does this helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676145/mac-windows-pop-up-virtual-keyboard-in-javascript  ?

Comment: yes, it helps a little bit, thanks! But there are two problems:
1 - For now, this is the most important: it is possible to close automatically the On-Screen-Keyboard when the user leave the focus from input text?
2 - This solution isn t 'universal': user must modify manually firefox's settings

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't believe it is possible to trigger the windows on-screen keyboard using JavaScript alone (assuming this is for a web page), you'll need to call upon a different script that operates outside of your browser (e.g. VBScript, etc).
2. a) this plugin is a tool that you can use in a page you are developing, but can't be used generically for everything; it will only exist in browser pages which you load it to.  If you want to include this plugin in a web page you are making, simply save the file in the page's js folder, then reference it in the script block of your HTML as follows: script src="js/jsKeyboard.js"

   b) The optional scan keys that is built into the windows keyboard is not part of the jQuery keyboard, but you could program that in as an optional function if you are familiar with JavaScript.